# jquery selector of parents

Tags: jquery, selector, parent, children

I have this html structure:

```
<div class="dropdownedit">
<div class="dropbtn">textxyz</div>
<div class="dropdown-content" style="display: none;">
<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text1">text1</div>
<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text2">text2</div>
<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text3">text3</div>
<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text4">text4</div>
</div></div>
```

in jquery I call a on-click-event for the class "ocond":

now I want to modify the text in class dropbtn (there are around 100 with this name). So i tried it with this jquery line:

```
  $(this).parents('.dropbtn').text("conditionvalue");
```

I also tried:

```
$(this).parents('.dropdownedit').siblings('.dropbtn').text("conditionvalue");
```

but I had no success. anyone can point me to the right selector? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$(this).parent()` to navigate from the `.ocond` to the `.dropdown-content`, and then you can use `.siblings('.dropbtn')` to get to the `.dropbtn` sibling:

```js
$('.ocond').on('click', function() {
  $(this).parent().siblings('.dropbtn').text("conditionvalue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdownedit">
  <div class="dropbtn">textxyz</div>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <div href="#" class="ocond" id="text1">text1</div>
    <div href="#" class="ocond" id="text2">text2</div>
    <div href="#" class="ocond" id="text3">text3</div>
    <div href="#" class="ocond" id="text4">text4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your

```
$(this).parents('.dropbtn')
```

didn't work because `.dropbtn` is not a parent of the `.ocond`s, and

```
$(this).parents('.dropdownedit').siblings('.dropbtn')
```

didn't work because the `.dropbtn` is not a sibling of the `.dropdownedit`.

You should probably only use `.parents` if you want to select *multiple* parents of the element in question - otherwise, probably better to use `.closest` (which will select *one* ancestor matching the passed selector) or `.parent` (which will select just the immediate parent element).

Comment: In the same on-click-event of class "ocond" I would like to add another sibling "<div href="#" class="ocond" id="text5">text5</div>". I tried it with :   $(this).parent().prepend('<div href="#" class="ocond" id="'+oldcondition+'">'+oldcondition+'</div>'); 
 but the selector seems to be wrong. do you know a correct one?